# Unresolved dependencies reported by sbt 0.13 in IntelliJ IDEA CE 12

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I'm using **IntelliJ IDEA CE 12** for Scala development. I have installed SBT plugin. Currently my `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/build.sbt` looks like this:

```
resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.7.0-SNAPSHOT")
```

My project was imported to IDEA without `auto-import`.

I noticed that my Scala classes are not able to find some imports, but I'm able to compile the project and run - so it works.

Developing with missing imports is quit hard ;) so I ran successfully `gen-idea` and tried to import my project once more with `auto-import` on. Unfortunately, I got the following error:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.slick#slick_2.9.2;2.0.0: not found
[warn]  :: io.spray#spray-json_2.9.2;1.2.5: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.9.2;2.2.0-RC1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

The project's `built.sbt` is as follows:

```
resolvers ++= List(
  "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io/",
  "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
)

libraryDependencies ++= List(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.0",
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "8.4-701.jdbc4",
  "org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.6.20",
  "io.spray" % "spray-can" % "1.2-M8",
  "io.spray" % "spray-routing" % "1.2-M8",
  "io.spray" %% "spray-json" % "1.2.5",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.2.0-RC1",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.1"
)
```

How can I resolve the dependencies in IDEA? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What scala version are you using? It seems to be `2.9.2`, but some of your dependencies do not exist for this version. Switching to `2.10.3` would probably resolve the problem.

Comment: Good point! I just realized that IDE used Scala compiler in version 2.9.2. I have some troubles with changing the compiler version to 2.10.3, because this version was marked as "Not Found" in project settings. I set scalaVersion property as 2.10.0 in my build.sbt and it works. Thank you! :)

Comment: @user3439736 Not that it changes much, but please replace `List`s to `Seq`s in `build.sbt`.

Comment: Ok I will. I just read that List in Scala is like a LinkedList in Java. Should I use Seq over List in build.sbt, because LinkedList is not efficient for random access to values or is there any other explanation?

Answer (score 4):

`UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES` are always about the small bits in dependencies that make sbt unable to find them in the available repositories.

You should always `inspect` the `resolvers` and `libraryDependencies` settings (as you did), but please note `%%` to construct a dependency.

From [Getting the right Scala version with %%](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html#getting-the-right-scala-version-with):

> If you use `groupID %% artifactID % revision` rather than `groupID % artifactID % revision` (the difference is the double `%%` after the
>   `groupID`), sbt will add your project's Scala version to the artifact
>   name. This is just a shortcut.

So, the combination of `resolvers`, `libraryDependencies` and `%%` (and `scalaVersion`) are usually causing many troubles to people new to sbt (and in fact, the other build tools as they too have to find the dependencies a developer sets in their project build files).

Use http://mvnrepository.com/ to check out whether your dependency is actually downloadable.

Let's pick, `"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.0"`. Given no `scalaVersion` specified in your `build.sbt` file (or any other build files), the `%%` was resolved to the default Scala version of the sbt launcher you use -- it could be **2.9.1** or **2.10.3** or something else. Somehow (I can't explain why given the information you provided) it picked **2.9.2**. There's no Slick at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.slick for the Scala version. You need to use the following (note the single `%`):

```
"com.typesafe.slick" % "slick_2.10" % "2.0.0"
```

or set `scalaVersion` to **2.10.3** which is currently the latest released version of Scala as follows:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.3"
```

Repeat for the other `%%` dependencies.

It could be that there are available `resolvers` that could offer such artifacts, but you'd have to be told about it explicitly as searching Internet and private repositories is usually a pain.

Comment: Thank you for your deep explanation. I was compiling my project via console successfully, because it uses version 2.10.3. I was not aware that IDE used version 2.9.2. I have already added scalaVersion property to my build.sbt and it works. Thank you for pointing me out that in unresolved dependencies I used %% syntax. This should brought my attention at the very beggining of this problem.

Answer (score 3):

> [warn]  :: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.9.2;2.2.0-RC1: not found

SBT is trying to resolve those dependencies for Scala version 2.9.2, you should add

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.3"
```

(actually, any 2.10.x should do) to your `build.sbt`.